# How to remove the "Currently:" tag and a link of a FileInput widget in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I made a ModelForm from a Model in Django, the model have an ImageField field on it. When I render the info of the form in a template for editing it, it show this:

[image: Screenshot that show Currently info]

How I can remove the 'Currently' tag and link??

Answer (score 6):

The Django Admin uses `AdminFileWidget` to render ImageFields. `AdminFileWidget` merely inherits from the standard `FileInput` widget and adds the extra "Currently" stuff. So just use `FileInput` instead:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ImageField: {'widget': forms.FileInput },
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forms.FileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput) to remove `Currently:` and a link.

For example, there is **`Image` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

Then, there is **`Image` admin** below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image

@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, `Currently:` and a link are displayed as shown below:

[image]

Now, if assigning `forms.FileInput` to [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image
from django import forms

@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): # Here               # Here
    formfield_overrides = {models.ImageField: {"widget": forms.FileInput}}
```

Then, `Currently:` and a link are removed as shown below:

[image]

In addition, if you override `forms.FileInput` and assign `CustomFileInput` to `formfield_overrides` as shown below. (*`</p>` can be removed because `</p>` is automatically added in Django):

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Image
from django import forms
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.db import models
                     # Here
class CustomFileInput(forms.FileInput): 
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        result = []
        if hasattr(value, "url"):
            result.append(
                f'''<p class="file-upload">
                      Presently: <a href="{value.url}">"{value}"</a><br>
                      Change:'''
            )
        result.append(super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer))
        # result.append('</p>') # Here
        return format_html("".join(result))

@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                      # Here
    formfield_overrides = {models.ImageField: {"widget": CustomFileInput}}
```

You can change `Currently:` to `Presently:` as shown below:

[image]