# How to not render django image field currently and clear stuff?

Tags: django

I took a look at following SO question, but had no luck. I don't know, maybe I didn't understand the answers.

1) [How to remove the “Currently” tag and link of a FileInput widget in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076154/how-to-remove-the-currently-tag-and-link-of-a-fileinput-widget-in-django)

2) [Django ModelForm ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822111/django-modelform-imagefield)

**My form:**

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company_logo = forms.ImageField(label=_('Company Logo'),required=False, error_messages = {'invalid':_("Image files only")})
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ("company_logo")
    ....
```

**My model:**

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    strg=CustomFileSystemStorage(strict_name='images/company_logo.png',save_format='PNG')
    company_logo=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True,null=True,storage=strg)
    .....
```

**After rendering:**

[image: imagefield]

I see from the first link, that the `models.ImageField` inherits the `FileInput` and adds the extra stuff, but I do not understand how to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution is:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company_logo = forms.ImageField(label=_('Company Logo'),required=False, error_messages = {'invalid':_("Image files only")}, widget=forms.FileInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ("company_logo")
    ....
```

I added the widget `forms.FileInput`, in order to tell the ImageField to use the basic field, not the one inherited from `FileInput`.

Comment: I was having the same issue with FileField. widget=forms.FileInput also did the trick! ex: image = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput)

Answer (score 9):

@mtndesign, you might also want a "remove" option, which you can place wherever you like in your template.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput)
    remove_photo = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if self.cleaned_data.get('remove_photo'):
            try:
                os.unlink(instance.photo.path)
            except OSError:
                pass
            instance.photo = None
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 7):

You can change the widget used to render the form field by specifying it on initializing:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    company_logo = forms.ImageField(label=_('Company Logo'),required=False, \
                                    error_messages ={'invalid':_("Image files only")},\
                                    widget=FileInput)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#fileinput) for widgets.

Comment: @mtndesign yeah, like 20 seconds apart ;)