# How to clear an image from image field in Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

Is there a way to display a tick box to clear an image as it has place when I edit a post?
[image: editing post]

When I am creating a new post and adding an image to the image field, then I cant clear the field. To remove the image, I would have to create a post and then edit it.

[image: New post]

Another question is, If I can change the label "Browse.." and "No file selected" to any other word?

Comment: Show your form code please. By default it shows clear options if you don't explicitly define to not to show clear option.

Comment: Go to -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336925/how-to-not-render-django-image-field-currently-and-clear-stuff